# Vim directory with macvim/terminalvim

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using mac vim in terminal via /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/vim

By now I didn't really care about what was in the MacVim directory in /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime
and still somehow I had proper syntax highlighting etc.. I guess my vim loaded the files from macvim?

Somehow I messed arround with snipmate and all the syntax highlighting stopped to work. Filetypes are correct, but no highlighting. So I copied the syntax folder from the macvim app to my ~/.vim/syntax and it worked like a charm. Is there a way how I can use the ones from the app again?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I found, that typing syntax on after vim has started removes even those plugin syntax capabilities. This holds true for resourcing my ~/.vimrc manually after the start. Allthough it is named by :scriptnames before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the syntax to your own `~/.vim/` directory effectively forks the factory-defaults. The downside is that **you** now have to update your copy whenever Macvim is updated.

The key to figuring out the problems is the `'runtimepath'` setting. By modifying that (in your `~/.vimrc`), you should be able to include the proper runtime files (and that is not just syntax, but also filetype plugins, should you have `:filetype plugin on`). BTW, it's unlikely this is caused by snipMate.

```
:set runtimepath?
```

Also, the `:scriptnames` command tells you exactly which scripts have been sourced so far.

Comment: I tried :scriptnames and it tells me, that some parts of the app are sourced, but by far not everything! 12: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim 13: ^/synload.vim 14: ^/syncolor.vim These are the only 3 syntax files.. out of 572. I included: set runtimepath=~/.vim,/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime,$VIMRUNTIME to my vimrc, but then even less files (in my ~/.vim) get sourced!

Comment: :!echo $VIMRUNTIME gives /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime

which is fine I guess, because I want that too. but also all the ~/.vim/ files

Comment: Only those syntaxes that you _use_ are sourced in addition to the ones you've listed.

Comment: But I use the same session all the time and it contains .vim (not working) and arduino (only specific syntax from plugin working, not cpp and c, which would apply too).
If i add the syntax folder in my ~/.vim those are working too.

Comment: By adding this line and restarting, it did the trick. 
set runtimepath^=~/.vim,/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime,$VIMRUNTIME

Just for reference I am starting vim through an alias from /Applications/MacVim.app/.../vim    
Now it loads all relevant syntax and indent and ftplugin files correctly. Thanks for the scriptnames and runtimepath hints!

Comment: Glad you've figured it out! Yes, I had a fix like that in mind.